# Header navigation with background images

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header + navigation that should look like this:

[image: header navigation]

However, I found some difficulties completing the task. What I have done so far, is to set a solid background for the header. Then, add the jagged (weave look-alike things) with ::before and ::after elements (also with background pictures) and so far it looks great, except that when I hover over an element, the :before and :after elements don't get colored with the same color as the hovered element (as the example in the picture).

Is my approach, the correct one or am I missing something? I have also thought about creating an Overlay Div on top of the whole header, but then issues will appear on different resolutions and also, I do not think that this fixes the original issue, different color on hover.

Do you guys have any ideas that could help, or materials that did I did not manage to find on the web?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/nbrLck99/1/

```
.main-nav::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/desktop-header-background.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: managed to upload and tun the image in jsfiddle.

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: @MinalChauhan sorry to bug you again, I uploaded the code and the image, please see the edited description

Comment: what i saw in the picture is, that header is already has a background that way and has no before after things. it's different with your code using before after and using a background image on before after. am i wrong? why won't you put more images so i can understand, with no blur one. @yavor.vasilev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work.

Your `:after` element is a background image. This means it isn't affected by by the `background-color` attribute. You'll have to create an `:after` element for every menu item and then alter it's background image with the `:hover` selector. You'll need an image for the default background and one for the hovered one. If you wish to have different "waves" you can create an image for each tab.

A quick preview:

```css
.main-nav {
    position: relative;
}
/* magic starts */
.level_1 > li > a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgsafe.org/a58a017b5d.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.level_1 > li:hover > a::after {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgsafe.org/a5f53cc8bf.png');
    z-index: 10;
}
/* magic ends */

.main-nav .level_1 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #0E5780;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.main-nav .level_1 li {
    position: relative;
}

.main-nav .level_1 li:hover {
    background-color: #f00;
}

.main-nav .level_1 > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}

.main-nav .level_1 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main-nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: #0f0;
}

.main-nav .level_1 > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul class="level_1">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">home</a>
                    <ul class="level_2">
                        <li><a href="">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">something</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">something</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: So as per my understanding, I still have to have an ::after for the .main-nav with the whole wave and create separate ::after elements for each of the elements in the navigation with the exact part of the wave that match the element, right? This doesn't sound responsive friendly (i need 768px + only, I have different design for smaller devices), or am I missing a key part again?

Comment: Yes, and you'll need to be sure the color from the entire nav's ::after is the same as the default for each tab or it will be visible.

Comment: Or you could use a [`mask`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) on the entire nav and just edit the hovered element's background color.

Comment: Those masks do not seem so bad, I might give it a try that way. Thanks a lot for all the help mate!